# Quick Help documentation opens at wrong topic

Tags: xcode, macos, documentation, macos-sierra

When I use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> on any attribute/function I get the `Quick Help`. For example:

[image]

However, when I click the `More` link (as shown in the screenshot above) it opens the documentation on the wrong page. Instead of the selected topic, it opens the documentation on the last page it was previously opened at.

Is this a bug? How can I open the documentation on the correct topic?

P.S. Currently I'm using Xcode 9.

Comment: The question is incomplete in its current state.

Comment: @EJoshuaS What do you mean?

Comment: It currently doesn't contain sufficient information to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue.

For me, this appears to happen when the documentation window is initially closed.So my workaround is to leave the documentation window open. It's just a momentary context switch on first use.

Comment: in my case documentation window was on the different Desktop screen. When I moved it to the same desktop it start to work. Thanks.